# More Ruby-esque way to code this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, refactoring, metaprogramming

I've got a method I'm calling expired? which is simply meant to check to see if its been more than 24 hours since my object has been updated, and if so return true. Here is my method, but although it works, it feels dirty, can anybody think of a better way to achieve my goal?

```
DAY_IN_SECS = 86400

def expired?
  return true unless (Time.now <=> self.updated_at + DAY_IN_SECS) == -1
end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use the `active_support` functionality, so:

```
def expired?
  self.updated_at > 1.day.ago
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Even in plain Ruby you could still do the simpler:

```
def expired?
  Time.now > self.updated_at + DAY_IN_SECS
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You're working with Rails, so you can use Rails Date/Time methods :).

For your problem, I like this :

```
def expired?
  updated_at.advance(:days => 1).past?
end
```